# Swift 3 array - remove multiple elements with help of other array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, closures

**Swift 3:**

I've two arrays, one is an array of the dictionary(json) and another is of indexes (Int value) of index Path (Collection type Index with element row & section). With the help of index rows of the second array, I need to remove, elements from the first array.

```
var arrayString = [ // Array with Json elements
  { "name" : "A" }, 
  { "name" : "B" }, 
  { "name" : "C" }, 
  { "name" : "D" }, 
  { "name" : "E" }, 
  { "name" : "F" }, 
  { "name" : "G" }, 
  { "name" : "H" } 
]
```

Now Second array (to be removed from the first array)

```
var arrayIndex = [ 2, 3, 5 ] // Array with
```

How can I do this?
I want resulting array like

```
var arrayString = [ 
       { "name" : "A" }, 
       { "name" : "D" }, 
       { "name" : "F" }, 
       { "name" : "G" }, 
       { "name" : "H" } 
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array `arrayIndex` is look like Array of `Int` not array of `IndexPath`.

```
arrayIndex.sorted(by: >).forEach { if $0 < self.arrayString.count { self.arrayString.remove(at: $0) } }
```

If `arrayIndex` is Array of `IndexPath` then use `row` property to remove the object from array.

```
arrayIndex.sorted(by: { $0.row > $1.row }).forEach { if $0.row < self.arrayString.count { self.arrayString.remove(at: $0.row) } }
```

Comment: Since removing an element from the array will affect the indices of the elements after it, you should ensure that the array of indices to remove is sorted in descending order

Comment: @Paulw11 Completely forgot that, thanx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional approach using `enumerated`, `filter`, `contains`, and `map` to create the array:

```
var arrayString = [
    [ "name" : "A" ],
    [ "name" : "B" ],
    [ "name" : "C" ],
    [ "name" : "D" ],
    [ "name" : "E" ],
    [ "name" : "F" ],
    [ "name" : "G" ],
    [ "name" : "H" ]
]

let arrayIndex = [2, 3, 5]

arrayString = arrayString.enumerated()
    .filter { !arrayIndex.contains($0.0 + 1) }
    .map { $0.1 }

print(arrayString)
```

> ```
> [["name": "A"], ["name": "D"], ["name": "F"], ["name": "G"], ["name": "H"]]
> ```

---

**Explanation:**

- `.enumerated()` takes the original array and creates an array of tuple pairs containing the index of each item paired with the item: `(index, item)`
- `filter` selects those items from the resulting array that return `true` from the passed (*trailing*) closure.  In this case, an item is selected if its index is not in `arrayIndex`
- `map` is used to pull just the `item` from the resulting array of tuples
- the index was increased by `1` because your example seemed to indicate that your `arrayIndex` started at `1` and not `0`